# Elasticsearch Docker stop seems to ignore SIGKILL

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch in Docker for local dev. While I can find containers that work, when `docker stop` is sent, the containers hang for the default 10s, then docker forcibly kills the container. My assumption here is that ES is either not on PID 1 or other services prevent it from shutting down immediately.

I'm curious if anyone can expand on this, or explain why this is happening more accurately. I'm running numerous tests and 10s+ to shutdown is just annoying when other containers shutdown after 1-2s.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait the 10 seconds, you can run a `docker kill` instead of a `docker stop`. You can also adjust the timeout on `docker stop` with the `-t` option, e.g. `docker stop -t 2 $container_id` to only wait 2 seconds instead of the default 10.

As for why it's ignoring the sigkill, that may depend on what image you are running (there's more than one for elasticsearch). However, if pid 1 is a shell like /bin/sh or /bin/bash, it will not pass signals through. If pid 1 is the elasticsearch process, it may ignore the signal, or 10 seconds may not be long enough for it to fully cleanup and shutdown.

Comment: Thanks. yeah, it looks like this is an issue that plagues just about every ES image I try, I'm thinking it has to do with cleanup time; most images have `CMD` set to start ES or Kibana. `-t` seems best.

Comment: Most of the images I saw used the json formatted `CMD` (to launch with exec instead of a shell), and if that `CMD` exec'd a shell script, that last line of the script was an `exec` to launch ES as the same pid. Those two pieces are needed to avoid having a shell as pid 1.